# Severe internet problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, internet

i have been having a lot of problems with my internet, the internet is by cable, and i using a motorola modem with a NETGEAR wireless router, the speed that i have is 10mbps.

First, my internet sometimes goes down without reason, almost all the times that this happened, it always showed the "resolving host" issue, tried to change the DNS servers in my router to the google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) didn't fix anything.

Sometimes the internet changes the IP address and the connection goes down, using a static IP in the router fix this, but it goes down anyway after some hours. (with DHCP the drops are between 2-3 hours, with static days)

Another problem is that sometimes my internet speed goes all down (the internet is online but the speed are literally in B/S) and most of the pages take years to load (or they just send a ping error)

The PC that i use is connected by a ethernet cable.

Comment: Your brand of modem is extremely sensitivity to noise on the line.  This type of problem is only something your provider can solve.

Comment: hello, how do i check the SNR?